# trouble implementing android notifications

Tags: android, notifications

I would greatly appreciate any help with troubleshooting my use of notifications within the Android emulator. I have tried several different versions without success and the code below seems to distill the needed elements down to the minimum. The problem is that the notification simply doesn't get sent. I hear the "click" noise when I tap the button in the emulator but nothing else.

I had read somewhere that having the wrong type of image may cause problems and I have tried several. The one I have included now is generated using Vector Asset within the res folder. It feels like there is something simple that I am missing but from what I can see from all the examples I have found online the basic elements are sound.

Any help or direction would be appreciated.

```
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    NotificationCompat.Builder notification;
    private static final int idNumber = 123;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
            notification.setAutoCancel(true);
        }

    public void sendNotification(View view){
        notification.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_android_black_24dp);
        notification.setContentText("This is the notification message");
        notification.setContentTitle("Notification");
        notification.setTicker("There is a notification");
        notification.setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis());

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        notification.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

        NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        nm.notify(idNumber, notification.build());
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow, please take a time to go through the [welcome tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to know your way around here (and also to earn your first badge), read how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also check [How to Ask Good Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so you increase your chances to get feedback and useful answers.

Comment: Notification creation code you posted looks ok. Are you sure it's called? (I don't see an onclick handler in the code)

Comment: The method is called (the onClick is set through the XML layout). When I run it in the debugger I can "click" the button and it jumps to the method. I can then run through it without any errors or other problems. It just doesn't produce a notification.